# C++11 - std::declval<T>() name of method

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Is there a way, how to pass a method name as template parametr after `std::declval<T>()`?

So far, I have this:

```
template<typename T, typename ... Args>
struct MethodInfo
{
    using type = decltype(std::declval<T>().foo(std::declval<Args>() ...)) (T::*)(Args ...);
};
```

But I would like the "`foo`" to be template parametr.

Comment: Not exactly what you've asked for, but would something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0197cd774882606c) meet your needs?

Comment: @TartanLlama No, because this it is not working for overloaded methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly what you asked but I think this may somewhat fit your need:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct MethodInfo {
    template<typename Ret>
    static auto get(Ret(T::*)(Args...)) -> Ret(T::*)(Args...);
};

struct Foo {
    int foo(int);
    int foo(int, int);
};

int main() {  
    static_assert(std::is_same<
                        int(Foo::*)(int), 
                        decltype(MethodInfo<Foo, int>::get(&Foo::foo))
                          >::value, "");
}
```

[Demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Vyr6Dfnwekqiyj7Q)

Because, the function name is a non-type template parameter, I think this is the only solution, up to now.

Comment: It is not what I asked, but this solution is better than my... it is working and I managed to wrap it to preprocessor macro, so code is short

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 you could do this, but it pretty much defeats the purpose of this class:

```
template<typename T, typename U, U ptr, typename... Args>
struct TypeOverload;

template<typename T, typename U, typename... Args, U(T::* ptr)(Args...)>
struct TypeOverload<T, U(T::*)(Args...), ptr, Args...>
{
    using type = decltype((std::declval<T>().*ptr)(std::declval<Args>() ...)) (T::*)(Args ...);
};
```

because the usage would be as follows:

```
using bar_t = TypeOverload<Foo, decltype(&Foo::bar), &Foo::bar, int, int>::type;
static_assert(std::is_same<bar_t, void(Foo::*)(int,int)>::value, "");
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xqZMDdwGJiaNOzaN)

---

But with `auto` template parameters in C++17, you could have this:

```
template<typename T, auto ptr, typename... Args>
struct TypeOverload
{
    using type = decltype((std::declval<T>().*ptr)(std::declval<Args>() ...)) (T::*)(Args ...);
};
```

and you'd use it as follows:

```
using bar_t = TypeOverload<Foo, &Foo::bar, int, int>::type;
static_assert(std::is_same<bar_t, void(Foo::*)(int,int)>::value, "");
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ECnhY0cIPH37jk89)

Comment: @TartanLlama right, I copied from the wrong window. That being said I just read OP's comment about overloads, so this answer will probably need to be deleted anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's really answerable if overloads need to be handled anyway, as you'd need to `static_cast` at the call site to disambiguate. I guess `foo` could be a member functor with a templated/overloaded `operator()`? That's the only way I can think of off the top of my head.

Comment: @krzaq It can handle overloads in your live demo. However, in Visual Studio 2015, it wont compile :/ - `'TypeOverload': template parameter 'Args' is incompatible with the declaration`, `'TypeOverload': too many template arguments`

Comment: @MartinPerry right, the ugly version that requires you to tell which overload you want should handle them, because it knows which one you want. I can't comment on VS2015, I don't have a test environment with it